# android recall activity

Tags: android

I have variable loopnum which I initialized it as `loopnum = 0;`

Now I wanna say that

```
 if(loopnum <6) 
  { 
    loopnum++; //And then recall the `Activity` from the beginning.
   }
```

How should I recall the `Activity`? should I define `loopnum` `static`? Because each time after recalling the activity, the value of `loopnum` will be lost.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it static so you will have only one loopnum instance.